# Annotation processor doesn't run in plain Java

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to make annotation processor in plain java (not android api), but anytime I run my main function, processor is supposed to stop build process because of error, but it doesn't.

My project structure is:

```
Root
  |-> core (all features including annotations)
  |-> annotation-processors (just annotation processor with set-up META-INF and processor class)
  |-> example (main void with class that is annotated with @Disable - annotation declared in core, this should stop compiler)
```

Annotation processor class is

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("jacore.support.Disable")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
public class Processor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private Filer filer;
    private Messager messager;
    private Elements elements;

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnvironment) {
        this.filer = processingEnvironment.getFiler();
        this.messager = processingEnvironment.getMessager();
        this.elements = processingEnvironment.getElementUtils();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> set, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
        for (Element element : roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Disable.class)) {
            if (element.getKind() != ElementKind.CLASS) {
                messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "@Activity should be on top of classes");
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton(Disable.class.getCanonicalName());
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latestSupported();
    }
}
```

I am using InteliJ IDEA and annotation processors are enabled in settings.
Annotation processor class may seem stupid, I really want to make it run, then I will improve features of it.

Edit:
There is build.gradle of 'example' module

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'sk.runner'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation project(":core")
    annotationProcessor project(":annotation-processors")
}
```

Comment: Do you see your error message in the compiler output?

Comment: @dnault no, but it is supposed to show error

Comment: This makes me wonder if the error code path is actually being executed. I'd try throwing an exception from within the annotation processor (instead of just printing the message). This is not the recommended approach, but it might give you a better indication of whether your processor is getting executed at all.

Comment: @dnault should I throw error in init or process or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @dnault added `throw new IllegalStateException();` to both init() and process() methods and project compiled anyway

Comment: @dnault + I tried adding annotation processor in settings -> Compiler -> Annotation processors and compiler threw `Error:java: Annotation processor 'jacore.processors.Processor' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Intellij IDEA, you should configure your build process entirely in gradle. This way it will be IDE-independent, and IDEA supports auto-sync with the gradle project.

In gradle you can try something like this, and then run the gradle 'build' task (or 'classes' task to only compile source):

```
task myCustomAnnotationProcessorTask(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build') {
    source = sourceSets.main.java
    classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    options.compilerArgs = ['-proc:only',
                            '-processor', 'jacore.processors.Processor']
}
compileJava.dependsOn myCustomAnnotationProcessorTask
```

Comment: I will try tommorow

Comment: I added this snippet to build.gradle and now all keywords (like dependencies, apply plugin, etc.) are greyed out saying "Cannot resolve symbol *). Program compiles successfuly but annotation processor doesn't run.

Comment: @Martin Maybe the build has some syntax error. If the build file is not valid, compilation should not work. How are you compiling your program? If you run "gradlew" from the project root (dir containing build.gradle) what output do you get?

Comment: I am running program using Intellij IDEA trought main function. I can try to run gradlew.

Comment: * What went wrong: Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.

Comment: Well, I changed gradle wrapper path so now it successfully built and annotation process has aborted java compilation. However I have to run this task as it's not included in build.