# Annotation Processing doesn't work in plain java 15

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processing

I am trying create a simple annotation (@NewIntent) and the class annotated with that should print hello world on the console.
What I want to achieve is annotate a class with something and be able to collect that the javadoc of that class and print it later (something like a help function that lists all commands).

As a small step towards that goal, I am trying to create custom annotations :D
However, i keep getting the following Exception:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AnnotationsTesting'.
    Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'custom' for task ':myCustomAnnotationProcessorTask' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.getProperty(ConfigureDelegate.java:130)
    at build_4bjccfv4xujp6uu49zc54jj7x$_run_closure4.doCall(C:\Users\k\IdeaProjects\AnnotationsTesting\build.gradle:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at 
    ... 140 more
```

I was following this [tutorial](https://iammert.medium.com/annotation-processing-dont-repeat-yourself-generate-your-code-8425e60c6657), but as you can see that is based on android, which shouldn't be a problem, but I wanted something in plain java, just to get an Idea of it and use it on later projects, but there are almost no java gradle tutorials that explain this (The only one I found was [this one](https://tomgregory.com/annotation-processors-in-gradle-with-the-annotationprocessor-dependency-configuration/), but it focuses on mapping, which is not what I need).

My project structure is as follows:

```
AnnotationsTesting
|-> custom-annotation
|-> custom-processor
|-> src.main.java.Main
```

where custom-annotation and custom-processor are other modules with their own build.gradle:

These are the dependencies of custom-processor:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'

    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '30.1-jre'
    compile group: 'com.squareup', name: 'javapoet', version: '1.13.0'
    compile group: 'org.kohsuke.metainf-services', name: 'metainf-services', version: '1.8'
    compile project(':custom-annotation')
}
```

I use JavaPoet to generate the java files and org.kohsuke.metainf-services to generate the META-INF because I was not confident enough to do it myself (and I also am unsure whether it is considered a good practise at all)

---

Below are the dependencies of the AnnotationsTesting project itself:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'

    compile project(':custom-annotation')
    annotationProcessor project(':custom-processor')
}

task myCustomAnnotationProcessorTask(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build') {
    source = custom-processor.main.java
    classpath = custom-processor.main.compileClasspath
    options.compilerArgs = ['-proc:only',
                            '-processor', 'javacore.processors.Processor']
}
compileJava.dependsOn myCustomAnnotationProcessorTask
```

The task in here comes from another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746233/annotation-processor-doesnt-run-in-plain-java). I understand that it is trying to tell the compiler to recognise my NewIntentProcessor as a Processor, but something seems to go wrong.

---

Lastly, here is my NewIntenProcessor.java:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName;
import com.squareup.javapoet.JavaFile;
import com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec;
import com.squareup.javapoet.TypeSpec;
import org.kohsuke.MetaInfServices;

import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind;
import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.util.Elements;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

@MetaInfServices
public class NewIntentProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private Filer filer;
    private Messager messager;
    private Elements elements;
    private Map<String, String> activitiesWithPackage;

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnvironment) {
        super.init(processingEnvironment);
        filer = processingEnvironment.getFiler();
        messager = processingEnvironment.getMessager();
        elements = processingEnvironment.getElementUtils();
        activitiesWithPackage = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> set, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {

        try {
            /**
             * 1- Find all annotated element
             */
            for (Element element : roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(NewIntent.class)) {

                if (element.getKind() != ElementKind.CLASS) {
                    messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Can be applied to class.");
                    return true;
                }

                TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement) element;
                activitiesWithPackage.put(
                        typeElement.getSimpleName().toString(),
                        elements.getPackageOf(typeElement).getQualifiedName().toString());
            }


            /**
             * 2- Generate a class
             */
            MethodSpec main = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("main")
                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC)
                    .returns(void.class)
                    .addParameter(String[].class, "args")
                    .addStatement("$T.out.println($S)", System.class, "Hello, JavaPoet!")
                    .build();

            TypeSpec.Builder helloWorld = TypeSpec
                    .classBuilder("HelloWorld")
                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL)
                    .addMethod(main);

            JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder("com.example.helloworld", helloWorld.build())
                    .build();

            javaFile.writeTo(filer);


            /**
             * 3- Write generated class to a file
             */
            JavaFile.builder("com.annotationsample", helloWorld.build()).build().writeTo(filer);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        return ImmutableSet.of(NewIntent.class.getCanonicalName());
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latestSupported();
    }
}
```

---

I am using the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA to develop this project
I look forward to code-improvement suggestions/other ideas and the help of the community :D

Comment: Your problem is `Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'custom' for task ':myCustomAnnotationProcessorTask' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.` which I can only assume means something is wrong with `source = custom-processor.main.java` and `classpath = custom-processor.main.compileClasspath`. It appears to be interpreting `custom` as a property, and that property does not exist. Perhaps you want to replace that with `project(":custom-processor")....`? Not sure though.

Comment: I tried, but Gradle doesn't like that...

`Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AnnotationsTesting'.
...
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object ':custom-processor' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection' `

Comment: I meant e.g. `source = project(":custom-processor").main.java`. Did you try that?